# Generic method for a map

Tags: java, generics

The implementation of these two methods are exactly same, except for the arguments part. I am wondering whether I can have a generic version of Java method to unify these two methods as one. Is it possible or what's the best way to do it? I am considering using a generic T, or Object type as the map key for both cases.

```
void mapPopulator1 (Map<String, Integer> map, String key)
{
    Integer value = map.get(key);
    if (value != null) {
        value = Integer.valueOf(value.intValue() + 1);
    }
    else {
        value = Integer.valueOf(1);
    }
    map.put(key, value);
}

void mapPopulator2 (Map<EventObj, Integer> map, EventObj key)
{
    Integer value = map.get(key);
    if (value != null) {
        value = Integer.valueOf(value.intValue() + 1);
    }
    else {
        value = Integer.valueOf(1);
    }
    map.put(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can have a generic method.

```
<T> void mapPopulatorGeneric(Map<T, Integer> map, T key)
```

This declares the generic type `T` with `<T>`, then use it for your parameter types.

Comment: But inside I used Integer.valueOf(), and that implies one argument must be an Integer?

Comment: @user2288494: That's why the second type parameter to the `Map` is still an `Integer` and not some other generic type.

Comment: It there a way to make the the second parameter also generic?

Comment: It is possible to make the second parameter generic as well, but then you'd have to change your method body, because you code right now is using `Integer`.

Comment: To change the body, I have to do a lots of instanceof testing, to decide what's specific type?

Comment: It looks like you're just adding one to the value, then putting the value back into the map.  You could have the second type parameter be `Number`, then test which subclass of `Number` you really have (`Double`, `Integer`, etc.) with `instanceof`, then implement subclass-specific logic.  But it sounds like a lot of extra effort.